# Pod missing homepage in Swift?

Tags: cocoapods, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I pod the JSQMessage library but got the error. Please help me how can i fix this. This is what i wrote in pod file:

```
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', :git => 'https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController.git', :branch => 'develop'
```

And the error:

```
[!] The `JSQMessagesViewController` pod failed to validate due to 1 error:
- ERROR | attributes: Missing required attribute `homepage`.
```

Answer (score 5):

If you forking it, just add `s.homepage = "https://LINKTOSOMETHING"` into your library .podspec

Comment: What if i am not forking it. ?

Comment: @ClementJoseph probably it still missing same, 'homepage' attribute, as it says in error. However, im not sure about more wide answer, just answered about my case and what worked in that case.